# LotusScript - How to escape double quotes in the SELECT statement?

Tags: select, lotusscript

I have a multiple documents which are containing the field named ***organization***.

Almost every second document contains double quotes in this field, for example: Medical Center "James Goodwin Corp." e.t.c

I have a search query with the name of some organization, which also contains quotes and trying to use this name in the search query to find all needed documents.

I have tryed many variants and each time I am getting the query syntax error about double quotes.

Can you please give some small example or some advise how to escape double quotes in the SELECT statement?

Thank you!

**Update:**

Yes, I am using Replace function like this:

```
searchValue = Replace(docByUi.search(0),{"},{|"|})
```

to change this double quotes to |"|.
And I am getting an error [in my select query](http://clip2net.com/s/3Plp4V3)
Or maybe I am wrong in something?

**Update #2:**

My query looks like this:

```
query = {Form="Person" & @Contains(} & docByUi.fields(0) & {;"} & searchValue & {")}
```

I meaned that I am already using {} to create a part-to-part query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use curly braces `{}` in your search statement. You don't need to escape double quotes inside braces.
Here is example of your search query:

```
Form = "Person" & @Contains(Level0; {Filia "Department of Y"})
```

In your lotus script you can use `|` symbol to make your string:

```
query$ = |Form="Person" & @Contains(| & docByUi.fields(0) & |; {| & searchValue & |})|
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have updated the question, can you look for the update?

Comment: @AlexeyTitarenko Use `|` symbol to make your query string.

Comment: Thank you! I have understood your advise. Now everything is working fine.  thank you :)

Comment: You can also use double-double-quotes. `query$ = "Form = ""Person"" & @Contains(" & docByUi.fields(0) & "; {" & searchValue & "})"` should work just as well. Not as readable, nempuBu4's code is therefore better, but I just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double quotes, use the pipe character:

```
Select @Contains(Organization; |"|);
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have updated my question, can you look for update?